# Do I have to rectify/crop images before process them with viso2_ros mono_odometry?

Tags: ros, monocular-camera, viso2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I'd like to understand if it's mandatory to rectify and crop images before process them with viso2_ros mono_odometry. I mean: does this latest library compute monocular odometry receiving unrectified images?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46018/do-i-have-to-rectify/crop-images-before-process-them-with-viso2_ros-mono_odometry?/) by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is mandatory to rectify the images before feeding them to [viso2_ros](http://ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros). And no, the library does not compute odometry using unrectified images.
To produce rectified images you can use the package [image_proc](http://ros.org/wiki/image_proc). Your camera driver should publish sensor_msgs/Image together with sensor_msgs/CameraInfo containing the calibration. image_proc then creates the rectified image for you which you can feed into viso2_ros.

A sample launch file would look like this:

```
<!-- example launch file for mono_odometer -->
<launch>
  <arg name="camera"/> <!-- camera must be set at launch -->
  <node name="image_proc" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" ns="$(arg camera)"/>
  <node name="mono_odometer" pkg="viso2_ros" type="mono_odometer" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="$(arg camera)/image_rect" />
    <param name="camera_height" value="0.5" /> <!-- cam is 0.5m above ground -->
    <param name="camera_pitch" value="0.0" /> <!-- cam is looking straight forward -->
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the documentation, it appears the answer is "yes":

> image (sensor_msgs/Image) The
> **rectified** input image. There must be a
> corresponding camera_info topic as
> well. Internally,
> image_transport::CameraSubscriber is
> used to synchronize between both.

from [MonoOdometer subcribed topics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros#Subscribed_Topics).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2